# Update table using sp_executesql in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can anyone help with this case? How to use a dynamic query to insert into table?

```
DECLARE
    @TypeCode varchar(25),
    @BomDateB varchar(25),
    @BomDateA varchar(25),
    @TbName varchar(25),
    @SQL varchar(max)

SET @TypeCode = 'PS-BPRG15AGW'
SET @TbName = 'z'+@TypeCode 
SET @BomDateB = '8/19/2016'
SET @BomDateA = '8/20/2016'

SET @SQL = 'UPDATE [PMLite].[dbo].['+@TbName+']
            SET [BOM Date] = '+@BomDateA+'
            WHERE [BOM Date] = '+@BomDateB+''

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: what exactly is problem here? Are You Inserting or Updating? The query You provided makes some errors?

Comment: there is error like this.  "Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'."

Comment: i want to update table with dynamic table name n parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be the correct approach to do your update:

```
DECLARE @TypeCode VARCHAR(25)
    , @BomDateB VARCHAR(25)
    , @BomDateA VARCHAR(25)
    , @TbName NVARCHAR(25)
    , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @TypeCode = N'PS-BPRG15AGW';
SET @TbName = N'z' + @TypeCode;
SET @BomDateB = '8/19/2016';
SET @BomDateA = '8/20/2016';

SET @SQL = N'
    UPDATE [PMLite].[dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@TbName) + '
    SET [BOM Date] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(24), @BomDateA, 121)
    WHERE [BOM Date] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(24), @BomDateB, 121);';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    , N'@BomDateB VARCHAR(25), @BomDateA VARCHAR(25)'
    , @BomDateB
    , @BomDateA;
```

Like I've said in comments, do not concat your dynamic SQL when it's not absolutely needed (see `@BomDateA` and `@BomDateB` parameters).

And instead of wrapping your text with brackets, use [`QUOTENAME()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx). This built-in function is used to wrap your object names into brackets and secures your code from [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Took from documentation:

> ## QUOTENAME (Transact-SQL)
>
> Returns a Unicode string with the delimiters added to make the input
> string a valid SQL Server delimited identifier.

Comment: Thumbs up for QuoteName

Answer (score 0):

Your @`SQL` should be `NVARCHAR`..

So change like below

```
Declare @Sql NVARCHAR(4000)
```

finally there will be some errors in your code ,[to avoid conversion issues](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7967/how-to-include-a-datetime-parameter-within-a-stored-procedure-along-with-string)..so

change  dates like

```
SET [BOM Date] = '+@BomDateA+'
```

to

```
SET [BOM Date] = '+''''+CONVERT(nvarchar(24), @BomDateA, 121)+''''+'
```

Comment: This is not right either... You should use proper parameters instead of string concatenation.